# How to execute exported Test suite in Selenium RC (Eclipse)?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

In Selenium IDE:

I have created one Test Suite : TS1.html and There are two test cases in it:
 Test1.html and
Test2.html

So What are the steps to execute this TS1.html test suite in Selenium RC (Eclipse)

Comment: Do you want to run .html format OR, do you want to convert it to another supported language? e.g. If you convert/export to Java/JUnit4/Remote control it will be save as .java extension

Answer (score 2):

1. In Selenium IDE click Options -> Options..
2. Here check the "Enable experimental features"
3. Click OK
4. Options -> Format -> JUnit 4 (Remote Control)
5. Click OK
6. Copy Paste the output to Eclipse

Should do the magic :)

Comment: after executing this Test suite, Blank page is displayed in firefox. So please suggest any solution for this

Comment: without knowing what the test suite looks like, its impossible

Comment: Or, you can also export the html code into the language of your choice from Selenium IDE. What language are you using? Java?

Answer (score 1):

For executing the .html file using Selenium server without converting to any other language (such as Java, C#, Ruby, Python, Perl, PHP etc.):

1. Open a terminal/command line
2. Go to the location where selenium-server.jar is located
3. Execute the following command:

java -jar selenium-server.jar -port 4546 -htmlSuite *firefox "http://www.google.com" "C:\SeleniumTest\TS1.html" "C:\result.html"

Tests will be executed in Firefox and Test Result will be generated as result.html in C drive.

Answer (score 0):

As Pavel said you first go to the **Options in Selenium IDE** and convert the recorded code into the **JUnit 4** model. Then copy and paste the code into the Eclipse IDE.

sample JUnit class with two testcase:

```
public class JUnitSample{

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup(){
        1)start the server
        2)Launch the browser
    }
    @Test
    public void testTestcaseName01(){
        paste your first test case 
    }
    @Test
    public void testTestcaseName02(){
        paste your second test case 
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void setup(){
        1)close the browser.
        2)Stop the server..
    }
}
```

One more thing the code which was converted by IDE is not sufficient to run from the Eclipse IDE. So, you have to modify the code to run from eclipse.